# github changes not appearing inside commits

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo, and a file inside it has changed at some point, however the change does not appear inside any commits, I looked through every single commit after the last one where the file was as it should be, and the commits did not register the file as having been changed at all?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the file where you made the change, click on the "blame" tab.

[image]

There you can see linewise who made the change, when it was made, and what commit the change was made to.

[image]

Comment: The change is not inside a commit :/

Comment: Are you sure you have pushed the change to github? If yes, you should see the change in your branch on github in the final commit. If you see the change, use the above "blame" technique i posted.

Comment: Please go throgh one of git and github tutorials on youtube, I think it would help you out a lot

Comment: The change definitely happened and it's definitely not in any of the commits